# Не происходит выборка из MySql

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, pdo

Создал *cms* на *php*. Использую *PDO* для работы с базой.
На денвере работает всё супер. Как только перенёс на хостинг, так и перестало всё работать. Как только скрипт пытается что-то получить из базы, выдаёт ошибку `500`. Где она происходит я вычислил.
Например до этого работает:

```
$user = DB::selectThis("users", "login, password", "WHERE login='{$login}'");
```

После уже нет. Никаких ошибок в журналах, абсолютно ничего. Файлы .htaccess смотрел все, ничего там такого нет.

Так же работает всё через **__autoload**.

Подскажите дорогие профи, в чём ещё может быть проблема?

Comment: "login, password" точно так пишутся? без кавычек посередине?

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin да точно, это подстановка полей таблицы просто.

Comment: Ок. Давайте по порядку. Работают ли страницы с PHP но без связи с БД? Далее: есть ли связь с БД вообще?

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin php работает, соединение есть. Буду счастлив просто если поможете, уже полдня голова болит.

Comment: Может стоит включить отображение ошибок? `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`, а также в PDO включить выброс исключения в случае ошибки в SQL

Comment: @VadimAshikhman спасибо огромное добрый человек, у меня оказывается не работало из-за того, что я пишу DB а имя файла с маленькой буквы стояло. Напишите как ответ плиз, я выберу его решаемым или как тут можно. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобраться помогло включение отображения всех ошибок, вместо пресловутой страницы с ошибкой 500.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо, я почему-то не подумал про вывод ошибок, вернее не знал, что они будут выводиться при 500 ошибке. Стыдно (.
Что означает третья строка? Куда её ставить? у меня стоит так:
    $opt  = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => TRUE,
            );

Comment: При инициализации объекта PDO можно как массив всех атрибутов передать (как у вас), так и поодиночке выставлять после инициализации. Она означает следующее: если во время выполнения SQL произойдет ошибка, PHP кинет исключение (\Exception) с текстом и кодом ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

> Никаких ошибок в журналах, абсолютно ничего.

Если в журналах ничего нет, то надо сделать так чтобы было.

```
ini_set('log_errors', 'On'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

А так, как написано в другом ответе, на боевом сервере делать нельзя никогда.

Отдельно хочу отметить чудовищность функции selectThis. Вместо того, чтобы использовать безопасные методы PDO, автор ваяет функцию, чтобы *сэкономить себе два слова в запросе*. И получает полную беззащитность перед SQL инъекциями.

Если бы не гонялся бы за экономией и передавал в функцию нормальный запрос, а отдельно - переменные для него, то писанины было бы совсем ненамного больше. Но зато это было бы действительно осмысленное использование PDO, а не переписывание на новый лад старых песен с mysql_query:

```
$user = DB::run("SELECT login, password FROM users WHERE login=?", $login);
```